# Scrolling WebBrowser programmatically sometimes doesn't work

Tags: .net, browser, webbrowser-control

I'm using the `System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser` control and I need to do programmatically scrolling.

For example, I use this code to scroll down:

```
WebBrowser.Document.Body.ScrollTop += WebBrowser.Height
```

The problem is that in some sites it works but in others it doesn't

```
http://news.google.com (works good)
http://stackoverflow.com/ (doesn't work)
```

It's can be something about the body code, but I can't figure out.
I've also tried:

```
WebBrowser.Document.Window.ScrollTo(0, 50)
```

but this way I don't know the current position.

Comment: Are you maybe trying to scroll before the document has been fully loaded?

Comment: no, the document is fully loaded

Answer (score 5):

This example works around quirks in scroll bar properties that can cause the behavior you are seeing.

You will need to add a COM reference to Microsoft HTML Object Library (mshtml) before this will work.

Assuming you have a WebBrowser named webBrowser1, you can try the following. I use a couple different interfaces because I have found that the values returned for the scroll properties are inconsistent.

```
            using mshtml;

// ... snip ...

            webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
            while (webBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
            {
                Application.DoEvents();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20);
            }
            Rectangle bounds = webBrowser1.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle;
            IHTMLElement2 body = webBrowser1.Document.Body.DomElement as IHTMLElement2;
            IHTMLElement2 doc = (webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument as IHTMLDocument3).documentElement as IHTMLElement2;
            int scrollHeight = Math.Max(body.scrollHeight, bounds.Height);
            int scrollWidth = Math.Max(body.scrollWidth, bounds.Width);
            scrollHeight = Math.Max(body.scrollHeight, scrollHeight);
            scrollWidth = Math.Max(body.scrollWidth, scrollWidth);
            doc.scrollTop = 500;
```

Comment: Note that if you set doc.scrollTop to a value larger than can be scrolled to, nothing will happen.

Comment: This works for me. You can avoid referencing mshtml by using reflection: var dd = browser.Document.DomDocument;                var doc = dd.GetType().InvokeMember ("documentElement", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, dd, null); doc.GetType ().InvokeMember ("scrollTop", BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, doc, new object [] { 500 });

Answer (score 4):

```
 webBrowser1.Document.Window.ScrollTo(new Point(50, 50));
```

this is an easy way to scroll to every point just input your